# Does "lesser" as in "lesser man" refer only to moral strength and goodness or can it encompass physical and mental stamina?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Does "lesser" as in "lesser man" refer only to moral strength and goodness or can it encompass physical and mental stamina?

Answer (score 2):

NOAD gives the meanings thus:

> **lesser** not so great or important as the other or the rest : *he was convicted of a lesser assault charge* | *they nest mostly in Alaska and to a lesser extent in Siberia*.
>
> • lower in terms of rank or quality : *the lesser aristocracy* | *you're looking down your nose at us lesser mortals*.
>
> • used in names of animals and plants that are smaller than similar kinds, e.g., *lesser spotted woodpecker, lesser celandine*.

But that doesn't tell the whole story. The term "lesser" may refer to someone who is not as great as another by any measure one chooses.

> I can drink 12 beers in an hour, where a lesser man might manage only six.
>
> Karen was no dummy, but her mother always considered her a lesser light than her sisters.
>
> Sir Robert the Lesser was called that because he was nowhere near as corpulent as Sir Robert the Greater.

Comment: 'lesser man' could also be a measure of, uh, 'manhood'. You know...

Answer (score 0):

Would be more useful to see it in a full sentence, but what seems clear is that it would refer to the particular subject of conversation (stamina, mental power, bravery, etc)

Saying that, I would use 'less of a man'